# C++ user defined conversion from composite object to float

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'll describe the question by means of what I'm trying to achieve.

Imagine you have a **Parameter** class:

```
class Parameter
{
private:
    float _parameter, _parameterScaler;

public:

    Parameter()
    {
        _parameter = 1;
        _parameterScaler = 0.5;
    }

    void SetValue(float value)
    {
        _parameter = value;
    }

    void SetValueOffset(float value)
    {
        _parameterScaler = value;
    }

    float "use of variable of this class"
    {
        return _parameter * _parameterScaler;
    }

}
```

This class holds two floats, one of which is *parameter value*, and another is *parameter multiplier*.

Now if I use the variable of type **Parameter** as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Parameter param;
    param.SetValue(5);
    param.SetValueOffset(0.5);

    printf("%6.2f", param);
}
```

It prints: 2.5.

I could achieve such an effect with operator overloading using () for example. Is it possible just with variable usage?

Comment: Write float() casting operator. In printf you still need to cast param to float - printf is not type-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not, because `printf` doesn't do anything to the parameters - doesn't apply casts or conversions and is oblivious to their types.

What you can do is use `std::cout` instead and overload `ostream& operator << (ostream& str, const Parameter&)`, that way

```
std::cout << param;
```

will print exactly what you want it to print.

The code `printf("%6.2f", param);` just treats `param` as if it were a `float` without doing any casting (and is overall bad). **Don't do it!**

Comment: Also note that many compilers will complain about the class not being a POD when compiling this.